# python string format with both list and string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to use string formatting to insert variable values into mystring where some of the variables are normal values and some are list values.

```
myname = 'tom'
mykids = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
mystring = """ hello my name is %s and this are my kids %s, %s, %s """ 
    % (myname, tuple(mykids))
```

I get the error not enough arguments because i probably did the `tuple(mykids)` wrong. help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.format()` instead:

```
>>> myname = 'tom'
>>> mykids = ['aa','bb','cc']
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is {} and this are my kids {}, {}, {}'.format(myname, *mykids)
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and this are my kids aa, bb, cc
```

Note the use of `*mykids` which unpacks the list and passes each list item as a separate argument to `format()`.

Notice, however, that the format string is hardcoded to accept only 3 kids. A more generic way is to convert the list to a string with `str.join()`:

```
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is {} and this are my kids {}'.format(myname, ', '.join(mykids))
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and this are my kids aa, bb, cc
>>> mykids.append('dd')
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is {} and this are my kids {}'.format(myname, ', '.join(mykids))
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and this are my kids aa, bb, cc, dd
```

The latter method also works with string interpolation:

```
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is %s and this are my kids %s' % (myname, ', '.join(mykids))
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and this are my kids aa, bb, cc, dd
```

Finally you might want to handle the case where there is only one child:

```
>>> one_kid = 'this is my kid'
>>> many_kids = 'these are my kids'
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is {} and {} {}'.format(myname, many_kids if len(mykids) > 1 else one_kid, ', '.join(mykids))
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and these are my kids aa, bb, cc, dd
>>> mykids = ['aa']
>>> mystring = 'hello my name is {} and {} {}'.format(myname, many_kids if len(mykids) > 1 else one_kid, ', '.join(mykids))
>>> print mystring
hello my name is tom and this is my kid aa
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to do it:

```
%(myname, mykids[0], mykids[1], mykids[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

This is another possible way,

In `python 2.7.6` this works:

```
myname = 'Njord'
mykids = ['Jason', 'Janet', 'Jack']
print "Hello my name is %s and these are my kids,", % myname
for kid in kids:
    print kid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> mystring=" hello my name is %s and this are my kids %s, %s, %s " %((myname,) + tuple(mykids))
>>> mystring
' hello my name is tom and this are my kids aa, bb, cc '
```