# Pythons multiple print result in starge outcome

Tags: python, printing, console

I have an issue with some print in my python code.

In this code I have a part where I have multiple print statements which result in a shiftet output in console.

Part of the code:

```
print ("Text 1")
print ("Text 2")
print ("Text 3")
print ("Text 4")
print ("Text 5")
```

The result I was expecting is following:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4
Text5
```

Instead I get something like:

```
Text1
      Text2
            Text3
                  Text4
                       Text5
```

Can someone explain me that and how to get rid of it?
I need to say that this only happens during the start of the program as I have a listener on key inputs. so when I press a key several times the line then is at some point correctly switched after each press like so:

```
Text1
      Text2
            Text3
                  Text4
                       Text5
                             Key pressed
                                         Key pressed 
Key pressed
Key pressed
Key pressed
```

EDIT:
Here is a minimal code that produces such an outpu with python 2.7 version

```
import sys
import termios
import tty
import pigpio
import time
from thread import start_new_thread

abort = False

pi = pigpio.pi()

def getCh():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch


def checkKey():
    global abort
    while True:
        c = getCh()
        if c == 'x' and not abort:
            abort = True
            break

start_new_thread(checkKey, ())

print ("+ / - = Increase / Decrease brightness (each by 10)")
print ("f / s = Increase / Decrease cycle speed")
print ("c     = Switch cycle speed steps")
print ("p / r = Pause / Resume")
print ("i     = Print info")
print ("x     = Abort Program")

while abort == False:
    time.sleep(0)

print ("Aborting...")
pi.stop()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve],

Comment: @Kevin, I added the code example

Comment: @LostKatana, maybe try passing those multiple print statements to *one* print statement using [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822448/1248974)

Comment: @downshift, when I only start a program with just the print statements without all the stuff in front this works like expected. I assume this hase something to do with the code along? But I couldn't find some clue.